# Install pynetbox on a Docker AWX

Tags: ansible-awx

Im running AWX in a Docker container.

How is it possible to install pynetbox in the AWX Container?

Im trying to run the nexbox module from AWX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this command:

docker container exec -it awx_task /bin/bash

pip3 install pynetbox